# Is there an advantage to Lambda Powertools’s Parser over straight Pydantic?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pydantic

I’ve got models which inherit Pydantic’s BaseModel and I use this to define my model attributes and do some validation.

But I see that [Lambda Powertools comes with a Parser](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.5.0/utilities/parser/#install) module which uses Pydantic.

Now that I want to use these models within an AWS lambda execution, is there a benefit to using:

`from aws_lambda_powertools.utilities.parser import BaseModel`

Instead of sticking with my existing

`from pydantic import BaseModel`

I can see that the Powertools Parser comes with a useful BaseEnvelope - but is BaseModel in Powertools any different?

And as a followup, if there is a benefit, could I monkey patch within the lambda runtime so I can:

1. Keep my models independent of anything Lambda like.
2. Spare myself from changing all the imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to update your imports. AWS Lambda Powertools's BaseModel is [just a re-export of Pydantic's BaseModel](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-powertools-python/blob/20ca7ed2203dea699ec0375c2797b1d505b42b66/aws_lambda_powertools/utilities/parser/__init__.py#L6).